# Git status reports changed files when nothing have been changed on merge

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository with more than 1350 commits and  several branches. Every time I want to pull some changes from Github, I get stuck in a situation that a bunch of files are modified but they aren't. They are always the same and I can discard those "changes" until I run both "git checkout" and "git reset" commands random times in different order.

Anybody have a clue about what is going on? Could the size of the repository? if it is, is there anything I can do in order to reduce the size like deleting old commits or something similar?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

**Edit:**

This issue also happens when I pull from master. This is how I reproduce this issue:

1. I commit a file in my local repo
2. The repo is clean without anything pending to be committed.
3. I pull first to get the latest changes from remote
4. Git reports that some changes will be overwriting by merge but those files haven't been changed in my commit or in the pending commits in remote.

This issue happen randomly even if my co-workers using the same OS as me (I'm using Ubuntu).

Comment: What does `git status` say before you try and pull?

Comment: One of the most frequent culprits in cases like this is different line-ending conventions and not having the appropriate `git` configuration options set accordingly.

Comment: @bcmcfc It says that nothing needs to be committed, that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: @twalberg which options you think need to be set up correctly?

Comment: @Vistiyos That depends on what line ending differences there are (Windows vs Linux, or Windows vs Mac, or Mac vs Linux, or some other mix even). But see `git help config` and look at things like `core.eol`, `core.autocrlf`, `core.safecrlf` and `core.whitespace`. There may be a couple others, but those I remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @twalberg thank for that, but I'm afraid is not OS related, one of my co-worker has the same OS (Ubuntu 14.04) as me and we are who use the repository mostly. I will investigate those configuration parameters to see if they help

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of files have been modified is surely caused by the out-sync, in other word, commit histories are different between local repository and remote on GitHub. Before pull from remote, you need to verify steps below:

1. `git fetch`, it fetch from remote and put it in `.git` folder, it has no effect on your local repo working directory and stage area
2. Switch your local branch to A, `git checkout A`
3. Find out-sync commits which exist in local branch A but not in remote branch origin/A. `git log origin/A..A`, if it has output after the command, you need to push the changes to remote firstly, and then do these steps again.
4. Find out-sync commits which exist in remote branch origin/A but not in local branch A.  `git log A..origin/A`, if it has output after the command, that means you need to pull from remote.

**Note:** before you pull from remote, please make sure step3 has no output.

Comment: It also happens when I make a pull from master, sorry I forgot to add that to my original question.

Comment: Did you compare the SHA-1 values from `\.git\refs\heads\master` and `\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master`? If the values are same, files in master branch should not be modified.

Comment: but it should be different if there are changes in remote that I don't have in my local repo, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean after `git fetch` they should stay same. So the changed files may be caused by pull changes from remote.

Comment: @Vistiyos, hi, have you solved the issue so far? If the answer it helpful please mark it, otherwise, you can write an answer which helps you and mark it 24 hours later. It will be helpful for others who have similar question.